# SailsJs v1.2.3 use FirebaseWaterline Adapter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, sails.js

I installed the blow link for using firebase in sails js but got this error:
npm install sails-firebase --save

in datastores.js:

```
module.exports.datastores = {

  default: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dashboard-auth'
  },
  firebase: {
    adapter: 'sails-firebase',

    credential: {
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "client_email": "sample@gmail.com",
      "client_id": "sample@gmail.com",
      // "client_x509_cert_url": "<YOUR CLIENT X509 CERTIFICATE>",
      "private_key": "MY API KEY",
      "private_key_id": "MY API KEY",
      "project_id": "myApp",
      "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "type": "service_account",
    },

    databaseURL: "https://myApp.firebaseapp.com",
  }

};
```

Error:
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

The adapter used by the `firebase` datastore is not compatible with
the current version of Sails/Waterline.

The adapter should expose a valid `adapterApiVersion`.

If you're using Sails ≥1.0, try:
npm install sails-firebase@latest --save

after that i used "npm install sails-firebase@latest --save" but not work :(
is there any npm package or any method for using firebase?

Comment: is it solved? If so share the solution ^^ I am currently using sails-firebase as the only datastore defined under 'default' and it's working, with few issues

Comment: No unfurtunately and I left it because it was not required for me.
anyway if you solve share with me:)